# Is there a name for a family of subsets which satisfies the finite matroid axioms and the ground set is infinite?

Tags: terminology, definition, matroids

I know that finitary matroids are those which can have potentially infinite ground sets yet have an additional axiom regarding  additional axiom. I was wondering if there are any widely used terms for the family of subsets of an infinite ground set just satisfying the finite matroid axioms?

Answer (score 0):

Oxley calls those pre-independence spaces, see e.g. [https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/infinitematroidschapter.pdf](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Eoxley/infinitematroidschapter.pdf)